# Rails3 + Drag & Drop + multiple file upload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

I'm looking for the best practice of uploading multiple files with drag and drop function on a Rails (3.2.8) app.
I'm considering using the following libraries/gems:

**Gems**

- [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave)
- [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

**JavaScript**

- [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)
- [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/)
- [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)
- [jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin v1.48 (2012-07-19)](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/)
- [valums/file-uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader)

What is the best/simplest combination?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload directly to Amazon S3, you can use [s3_direct_upload gem](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload) which uses jQuery File Upload. It's pretty simple to implement.